# OpenCV closing a shape and filling it

Tags: c++, opencv, shapes, fill, contour

I want to output a blue-filled hand but get the incorrect output. I've included the input picture, incorrect output picture and code below.

i think the code below does not fill the whole image because the image isn't closed yet at the right boundary.

how do i close the shape and fill it with blue properly?

[image: close shape]

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void drawStuff();
void showInputWindow();
void showCannyWindow();
void showContourWindow();

int thresh = 40;
int max_thresh = 120;
Mat img_rgb,img_gray,img_bw,canny_output,drawing;

int main(){
    img_rgb  = imread("qq.jpg");
    blur( img_rgb, img_rgb, Size(3,3) );
    cvtColor(img_rgb,img_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    showInputWindow();

    drawStuff();
    cv::waitKey(0);
}

void drawStuff(){
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    Canny( img_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
    cv::dilate(canny_output, canny_output, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1));
    showCannyWindow();

    findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
    drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    vector<Point> approxShape;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
        approxPolyDP(contours[i], approxShape, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.04, true);
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, Scalar(255, 0, 0), CV_FILLED);   // fill BLUE
    }

    showContourWindow();
}

void showInputWindow(){
    cv::namedWindow("InputImage");
    cv::imshow("InputImage",img_rgb);
}

void showCannyWindow(){
    cv::namedWindow("Canny");
    cv::imshow("Canny",canny_output);
}
void showContourWindow(){
    cv::namedWindow("Fill");
    cv::imshow("Fill",drawing);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that there are contours detected inside the hand. Try an inverse approach - fill the surroundings and then invert it.

Comment: how do you fill the surroundings?

Comment: Draw only the contours (not filled) using some distinct color such as green, then use cvFloodFill seeded at the top left corner (coords 0, 0) and fill it with blue. Then walk the image and replace blue pixels with black and black or green pixels with blue.

Comment: this time it fills the inverse including inside the hand. i think it's because there's an opening in the right boundary. am i correct?

Comment: @Og Namdik Sorry, I might have misunderstood, but why do you not find contours in the output you presented (external contours only). and then draw them...?

Comment: Yes, it is likely that there are holes in the contours. Try to use cvDilate followed by cvErode to close small gaps.

Comment: it still doesn't work. what values should i put in the parameters of the cvErode function?

Comment: `cvErode(src, dst, NULL, 1)`, the same as for cvDilate. The "1" means how big gaps (in pixels) will be closed.

Comment: @dark_charlie can't still seem to get the correct output. is there a way to close the right boundary?

Comment: It is closed by image edge, isn't it?

Comment: Look at the solution provided as an answer by me.

Answer (score 9):

To solve your problem, you should detect only outer contours. By doing that you will get only one contour, and you can fill it with your color.

```
findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```