# How to get separate contours (and fill them) in OpenCV?

Tags: c, opencv

I'm trying to separate the contours of an image (in order to find uniform regions) so I applied cvCanny and then cvFindContours, then I use the following code to draw 1 contour each time I press a key:

```
for( ; contours2 != 0; contours2 = contours2->h_next ){
        cvSet(img6, cvScalar(0,0,0));
        CvScalar color = CV_RGB( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );
        cvDrawContours(img6, contours2, color, cvScalarAll(255), 100);
        //cvFillConvexPoly(img6,(CvPoint *)contours2,sizeof (contours2),color);
        area=cvContourArea(contours2);
        cvShowImage("3",img6);
        printf(" %d", area);
        cvWaitKey();
    }
```

But in the first iteration it draws ALL the contours, in the second it draws ALL but one, the third draws all but two, and so on.

And if I use the cvFillConvexPoly function it fills most of the screen (although as I wrote this I realized a convex polygon won't work for me, I need to fill just the insideof the contour)

So, how can I take just 1 contour on each iteration of the for, instead of all the remaining contours?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change the last parameter you are passing to the function, which is currently `100`, to either `0` or a negative value, depending on whether you want to draw the children.

According to the documentation (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html#drawcontours),
the function has the following signature:

```
void cvDrawContours(CvArr *img, CvSeq* contour, CvScalar external_color,
CvScalar hole_color, int max_level, int thickness=1, int lineType=8)
```

From the same docs, `max_level` has the following purpose (most applicable part is in bold):

> max_level – Maximal level for drawn contours. **If 0, only contour is
>   drawn**. If 1, the contour and all contours following it on the same
>   level are drawn. If 2, all contours following and all contours one
>   level below the contours are drawn, and so forth. **If the value is
>   negative, the function does not draw the contours following after
>   contour but draws the child contours of contour** up to the
>   $|\texttt{max_ level}|-1$ level.

## Edit:

To fill the contour, use a negative value for the `thickness` parameter:

> thickness – Thickness of lines the contours are drawn with. If it is
>   negative (For example, =CV_FILLED), the contour interiors are drawn.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it, I hadn't noticed that parameter. Now I just need to fill them, is there any function for that? If not, how could i go about it? maybe watershed would work for the closed ones, but sometimes there are open contours as well.

Comment: Use a negative value for the thickness parameter. If that doesn't work for you, maybe one of these will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929197/opencv-closing-a-shape-and-filling-it , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716274/fill-the-holes-in-opencv

Comment: Thanks again, Using a negative thickness does the trick perfectly.

Comment: Gerardo, vote up and accept this answer if it worked for you.