# OpenCV findContours: make it robust

Tags: java, opencv, contour, threshold

How to make findContours robust to make it work even the the contour might not be closed due to noisy data and/or week edges/gradients in the image?

For the first case (not closed) I'm running into the following problem:
The algorithm runs quite well when using it on a thresholded picture like this:

[image]

But when I take a closer picture, then there is no closed contour, see here:

[image]

How to make it work for this case also? I thought of maybe always drawing a horizontal line at the top and at the bottom of my picture which will then always "cross" the papernote (when the note is captured from too close) making it a full contour. But this wouldn't probably work too well when the note is a bit rotated as I would then NOT get the correct contour, do I!?
Do you have any better ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution which might just work.

If you know which contour points are the openings to the gap (pseudo-code ahead):

```
Point pointGAP1;
Point pointGAP2;

if (pointGAP1.coordinate == iamgeBorder || pointGAP2.coordinate == iamgeBorder) {
    // add line from pointGAP1 to pointGAP2
}
```

Comment: Problem is, that I dont even get a contour at all because it is not closed, so I cannot implement your idea. I'm using the following `Imgproc.findContours(I,contours,new Mat(),Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` or is it because of `Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` that I only get a contour if its a valid closed rectangle? Do I need to change the call of the function to make it give me open contours as well!?

Comment: Yes if I remember correctly one of the parameters makes findContours output open contours.

Comment: Maybe I was mistaken about the parameter, but check this question which addresses that problem, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12929197/1085483

Comment: Unfortunately no. I already tried dilate/erode, but it doesn't close big gaps which can occur in my case :(